# How to config NatTable to select entire row not single?

Tags: row, nattable

I used NatTable to create table.

But I don't know how to config it to apply to select entire row not single.

As follows
[image]

Comment: please show code for your current config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `RowSelectionModel`. The following snippet is extracted from the `_5052_RowSelectionExample` of the NatTable Examples.

```
// use a RowSelectionModel that will perform row selections and is able
// to identify a row via unique ID
selectionLayer.setSelectionModel(new RowSelectionModel<Person>(
selectionLayer, bodyDataProvider, new IRowIdAccessor<Person>() {

    @Override
    public Serializable getRowId(Person rowObject) {
        return rowObject.getId();
    }

}));

// register the DefaultRowSelectionLayerConfiguration that contains the
// default styling and functionality bindings (search, tick update)
// and different configurations for a move command handler that always
// moves by a row and row only selection bindings
selectionLayer.addConfiguration(new DefaultRowSelectionLayerConfiguration());
```

The best way to learn about NatTable is to have a look at the NatTable Examples Application. It is available as a WebStart application via the [NatTable homepage](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/). Or you can download the examples jar file and execute it from [command line](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=getting_started) if WebStart doesn't work.

The example to look at is located under *Tutorial Examples -> Layers -> Selection -> RowSelectionExample*